# A question regarding Dyson equation and Green's function

Tags: many-body, greens-functions

When knowing the self-energy, I can derive the many-body Green's function as

$$ G(\mathbf{r}_i,t_i ; \mathbf{r}_f,t_f) = G_0(\mathbf{r}_i,t_i ; \mathbf{r}_f,t_f) + \int \mathrm{d} \mathbf{r}_1 \int \mathrm{d} t_1 \int \mathrm{d} \mathbf{r}_2 \int \mathrm{d} t_2 G_0(\mathbf{r}_i,t_i ; \mathbf{r}_1,t_1) \Sigma(\mathbf{r}_1,t_1 ; \mathbf{r}_2,t_2) G(\mathbf{r}_2,t_2 ; \mathbf{r}_f,t_f)$$

I would like to demonstrate that the very simple property

$$ G(\mathbf{r}_i,t_i ; \mathbf{r}_f,t_f) = \int \mathrm{d} \mathbf{r}_1 G(\mathbf{r}_i,t_i ; \mathbf{r}_1,t^*) G(\mathbf{r}_1,t^* ; \mathbf{r}_f,t_f) $$

holds for the $G$ as defined from the Dyson equation, for any $t^*$ such that $t_i < t^* < t_f$.

This is elementary to show in terms of diagrams (two connected bold lines make a single, longer bold line) but I struggle to demonstrate it analytically...

Comment: Are you sure this property really takes place? If the take into account that convolution of Green's functions in real space means multiplication of their Fourier transforms $G(\mathbf{p},\omega)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), the we get $G(\mathbf{p},\omega)=G^2(\mathbf{p},\omega)$, which is not true.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment! That's exactly the inconsistency I was running into, which motivated me to ask. However it seems that the property is quite general, see for instance (as pointed out below) Feynman and Hibbs, pag. 37, Eq. (2.31).

Comment: Note that the convolution is only on the spatial argument, this would imply $G(\mathbf{p},t+s) = G(\mathbf{p},t) G(\mathbf{p},s)$. Is this more reasonable?

Answer (score 3):

From the definition of Green function
$$
\psi({\bf r},t)=\int d^3x'dt'G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}',t')\psi({\bf r}',t').
$$
Add an intermediate step as
$$
\psi({\bf r},t)=\int d^3x'dt'G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}',t')
\int d^3x''dt''G({\bf r}',t';{\bf r}'',t'')\psi({\bf r}'',t'').   
$$
Just note that the integration variable is a dummy index and exchange $t'\rightarrow t''$. This gives
$$
\psi({\bf r},t)=\int d^3x''dt''G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}'',t'')
\int d^3x'dt'G({\bf r}'',t'';{\bf r}',t')\psi({\bf r}',t').   
$$
One has, after exchanging the integration order,
$$
\psi({\bf r},t)=\int  d^3x'dt'd^3x''dt''G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}'',t'')
G({\bf r}'',t'';{\bf r}',t')\psi({\bf r}',t').   
$$
But this must be equal to the integral we started from and so
$$
   G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}',t')=\int d^3x''dt''G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}'',t'')
G({\bf r}'',t'';{\bf r}',t').
$$
This can be easily obtained by path integrals (see Feynman and Hibbs, pag.37).

ADDED AFTER OP's COMMENT: I will introduce the Fourier transform as
$$
   G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}',t')=\int d^3x''dt''\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}e^{ip\cdot x''}G({\bf r},t;p)\int\frac{d^4p'}{(2\pi)^4}e^{ip'\cdot x''}G(p';{\bf r}',t').
$$
This yields
$$
   G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}',t')=\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\int\frac{d^4p'}{(2\pi)^4}
   G({\bf r},t;p)G(p';{\bf r}',t')\int d^3x''dt''e^{i(p+p')\cdot x''}
$$
or
$$
   G({\bf r},t;{\bf r}',t')=\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}
   G({\bf r},t;p)G(-p;{\bf r}',t').
$$
Taking the Fourier transform with respect to $({\bf r},t)$, one has
$$
   G(k;{\bf r}',t')=\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}G(k;p)G(-p;{\bf r}',t').
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My question was exactly regarding the validity of inserting an intermediate step. As you point out it's very standard, and I was aware of that... However it leads to the inconsistency noted above by Alexey Sokolic, namely by Fourier-transforming your last equation, using the convolution theorem, one would get: $G(\mathbf{p},\omega) = G(\mathbf{p},\omega)^2 $. Which is absurd.

Comment: That comment is not correct. I have explained the question in the answer. Indeed, this is a rather common formula in textbooks and it would come out as a surprise to find it wrong by such an argument.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to clarify your answer. However I must also point out that Alexey Sokolik's comment is right and if you assume translational invariance for Green's functions, and take the Fourier transform w.r.t. to difference between of the space/time arguments, for instance $\mathbf{r}'-\mathbf{r}$, then you get the inconsistency he points out.

I am not saying textbooks are wrong. I am not saying your reasoning is wrong, I don't see any error. I am just pointing out an inconsistencies which must be related to some conceptual error by my part, which I still cannot identify.

Comment: I stand corrected, the convolution theorem applies only on the space part, one would get $G(\mathbf{p},t+s) = G(\mathbf{p},t) G(\mathbf{p},s)$. I am thinking if this looks more reasonable, but maybe I should open another question for that...

Comment: The point is that $G(p)$ should be seen as a distribution. This means that $pG(p)=0$ means $G(p)\propto \delta(p)$. So, to write $G(p)(1-G(p))=0$ implies a non-trivial functional equation for $G(p)$.